# hg push Connection refused

Tags: ssh, mercurial

I use a http://bitbucket.org private repository, usually works well, but now I can't do push.
When I try get this message:
hg push 
remote: ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Connection refused
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!

Many thanks.

Comment: What's the SSH url used to connect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connection refused means that either their firewall is blocking you or they are not running ssh on port 22 (the default). I would recommend either contacting their customer [support](http://bitbucket.org/help/Home) or talk to whomever gave you access.

Comment: Yes, try support, or ask on #bitbucket on freenode.

Answer (score 0):

Since port 22 was blocked, I used the alternate URL ssh://hg@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/account_name/repo_name/ as described [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/troubleshoot-ssh-issues-271943403.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and actually this solution helped me out:

```
vim ~/.ssh/config
```

Add these lines and save it.

```
Host github.com
    Hostname ssh.github.com
    Port 443

Host bitbucket.org
    Hostname  altssh.bitbucket.org
    Port  443
```

taken from https://gist.github.com/goddoe/5692bfc3cdc374d918a87882963edf36